# Kotlin comment formatting in IntelliJ/Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, comments, kotlin, javadoc

Is there a way to format long Kotlin comments in IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio the same way as Java comments when you set:

> Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin

When you turn this setting on, after formatting it turns this:

```
/**
 * This is my very very very long comment which probably should be multi-line....
 */
```

into this:

```
/**
 * This is my very very very long comment
 * which probably should be multi-line...
 */
```

I don't see the same option for Kotlin but maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19963) already reported, please follow it for updates.

Comment: Apparently not implemented yet in 2023.3.3.